# How can I constantly update tableview per 'location changes'?

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, reloaddata

Alright, so I have a tableview that, when the view is loaded, it's populated with Parse objects that have geopoints within a set range of user's current location. This works here:

```
let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Events")
        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: myGeoPoint, withinMiles: range)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print(objects)

                for object in objects! {
                    self.names.append(object["Name"] as! String)
                    self.descriptions.append(object["description"] as! String)
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue with this is I need to either have this table `reloadData` **constantly** OR just whenever the user's location changes which, I predict, will happen pretty frequently. Because it needs to display the items that are within range, I can't have the user drive somewhere and the table still display the items from the last location.

For other parts of the app I have just have the table refresh when a certain button is clicked, however I need to know how to properly update this table ALWAYS or whenever the user's location changes. I have attempted to use a timer set to a fraction of a second, but that caused issues and didn't seem to be the the correct way.

How can I do this? Regarding always updating the table, I have tried

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

But that does nothing. Looked at `loadObjects()` also, but had errors. What is the best way to achieve this?

EDITS:

```
if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
        {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            //locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() //so not always updating 
            locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // locations contains an array of recent locations, but this app only cares about the most recent
        // which is also "manager.location"
        myLoc = PFGeoPoint(location: manager.location)
        print("significant change - \(myLoc)")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        print("failed")
    }
```

Comment: Register to be notified of significant location changes and reload the table view immediately when the app is in foreground or set a flag and reload the table view when the app comes to the foreground.

Comment: what do you mean comes to foreground? is there a certain function to call?

Comment: No, there is a delegate method in AppDelegate which is called. I just wanted to point out that reloading the table view while the app is not active makes no sense.

Comment: Ok.. but I meant while they are using the app constantly update. Is there a way you would recommend tracking significant location changes? Just storing previous value in a temp or..?

Comment: Take a look at [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `distanceFilter` property to your location manager.

```
locationManager.distanceFilter = 50
```

Now it will only update the user's location if it has changed by 50 or more meters.

Comment: Ok I will do that - can you look at my edits and see if what Ive done will also work? It doesn't seem to be reloading the tableview, even though it is triggering a significant change in location

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: I don't see that you added this in your edit... You should put it inside the if statement.

Comment: Ok.. but my tableview does not seem to be reloading data. Thats more my problem. But thanks

Comment: Also with your edit should I be using the startUpdatingLocation() or significantlocationchange func?

Comment: I use didUpdateToLocation

Comment: right but in the if statement - the func i commented out or the significantlocationc‌​change one that i have?

Comment: You should put it where you put the locationManager = CLLocationManager(). Also I don't believe the line you commented out should be